# Targeted Simplify in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I generate very long and complex analytic expressions of the general form:

```
(...something not so complex...)(...ditto...)(...ditto...)...lots...
```

When I try to use [`Simplify`](http://documents.wolfram.com/mathematica/functions/Simplify), Mathematica grinds to a halt, I am assuming due to the fact that it tries to expand the brackets and or simplify across different brackets. The brackets, while containing long expressions, are easily simplified by Mathematica on their own. Is there some way I can limit the scope of [`Simplify`](http://documents.wolfram.com/mathematica/functions/Simplify) to a single bracket at a time?

**Edit:** Some additional info and progress.

So using the advice from you guys I have now started using something in the vein of

```
In[1]:= trouble = Log[(x + I y) (x - I y) + Sqrt[(a + I b) (a - I b)]];

In[2]:= Replace[trouble, form_ /; (Head[form] == Times) :> Simplify[form],{3}]

Out[2]= Log[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] + (x - I y) (x + I y)]
```

Changing `Times` to an appropriate head like `Plus` or `Power` makes it possible to target the simplification quite accurately. The problem / question that remains, though, is the following: [`Simplify`](http://documents.wolfram.com/mathematica/functions/Simplify) will still descend deeper than the level specified to [`Replace`](http://documents.wolfram.com/mathematica/functions/Replace), e.g.

```
In[3]:= Replace[trouble, form_ /; (Head[form] == Plus) :> Simplify[form], {1}]

Out[3]= Log[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] + x^2 + y^2]
```

simplifies the square root as well.

My plan was to iteratively use [`Replace`](http://documents.wolfram.com/mathematica/functions/Replace) from the bottom up one level at a time, but this clearly will result in vast amount of repeated work by [`Simplify`](http://documents.wolfram.com/mathematica/functions/Simplify) and ultimately result in the exact same bogging down of Mathematica I experienced in the outset. Is there a way to restrict [`Simplify`](http://documents.wolfram.com/mathematica/functions/Simplify) to a certain level(s)?

I realize that this sort of restriction may not produce optimal results, but the idea here is getting something that is "good enough".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this, but it can be a little tricky and depends on the structure of your actual expression. However, usually a product of a number of terms in brackets will have the head `Times`, and you can use `FullForm` to verify this:

```
In[1]:= FullForm[(a+b)(c+d)]
Out[1]= Times[Plus[a, b], Plus[c, d]]
```

You can use the higher-order function [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) with expressions with head `Times` the same way you use it with expressions with head `List`, and that may allow you to `Simplify` the expression one term at a time, like so:

```
Map[Simplify, yourGinormousExpression]
```

You can use [`Expand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Expand.html) on the result if you need to subsequently expand out the brackets.

**EDIT to add:** If you want to specify the forms that you do want to simplify, you can use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html) or [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) instead of one of the relatives of `Map`. `Replace` is particularly useful because it takes a [*level specification*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html), allowing you to only affect the factors in the topmost product. As a simple example, consider the following:

```
In[1]:= expr = Sqrt[(a + 1)/a] Sqrt[(b + 1)/b];

In[2]:= Simplify[expr]
Out[2]= Sqrt[1 + 1/a] Sqrt[1 + 1/b]
```

If you don't want to simplify factors that depend on `a`. you can do this instead:

```
In[3]:= Replace[expr, form_ /; FreeQ[form, a] :> Simplify[form], {1}]
Out[3]= Sqrt[(1 + a)/a] Sqrt[1 + 1/b]
```

Only the second term, which depends on `b`, has been changed. One thing to bear in mind though is that some transformations are done automatically by `Times` or `Plus`; for instance `a + a` will be turned into `2 a` even without use of `Simplify`.

Comment: Thanks this (and the other answers as well) helped a lot.

Comment: Just tested this useful tip having a list of variables {y1,y2,..} in place of "a" and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I beg to differ with my colleagues, in that using `Map` to apply `Simplify` to each subexpression may not save any time as it will still be applied to each one.  Instead try, [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAt.html?q=MapAt&lang=en), as follows:

```
In[1]:= MapAt[f, SomeHead[a,b,c,d], {4}]
Out[1]:= SomeHead[a, b, c, f[d]]
```

The tricky part is determining the position specification.  Although, if the expression you want to simplify is at the first level, it shouldn't be any more difficult then what I've written above.

---

Now if you would still like to simplify everything, but you wish to preserve some structure, try using the option [`ExcludedForms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html?q=Simplify&lang=en).  In the past, I've used to prevent this simplification:

```
In[2]:= Simplify[d Exp[I (a + b)] Cos[c/2]]
Out[2]:= Exp[I(a + b + c)](d + d Exp[c])
```

which Mathematica seems to like, so I do

```
In[3]:= Simplify[d Exp[I (a + b)] Cos[c/2], ExcludedForms -> {_Cos,_Sin}]
Out[3]:= d Exp[I (a + b)] Cos[c/2]
```

Also, don't forget that the second parameter for `Simplify` is for assumptions, and can greatly ease your struggles in getting your expressions into a useful form.

Comment: The ExcludeForms tip is nice, thanks! I just whish Mathematica had a way of exclusively including forms to simplify other than TransformationFunctions, which can not be set up for brackets...

Answer (score 1):

You should try `Map`.
In general, `Map[foo, G[a, b, c, ...]]` gives `G[foo[a], foo[b], foo[c], ...]` for any head `G` and any expression `foo`, so for

```
  Map[Simplify, a b c d e]
```

it gives

```
  Simplify[a] Simplify[b] Simplify[c] Simplify[d] Simplify[e]
```

Note you can denote `Map[foo, expr]` als `foo /@ expr` if you find that more convenient.